# How to call function with generic params in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create something like this as below

```
export function f1(param1: string, param2: string) {
    console.log('Hello', param1, param2);
}

export function f2(param3: string) {
    console.log('world', param3);
}

interface Metadata {
    functionName: string;
    functionParams: any;
}

const testMap: Map<string, Metadata> = new Map<string, Metadata>([
    ['action1', {functionName: 'f1', functionParams: {param1: 'any', param2:'any1'}}],
    ['action2', {functionName: 'f2', functionParams: {param3: 'any2'}}]
])
```

So basically I want to call f1 or f2 function after reading it through a testMap. The idea is to store all action and their mappings against a function and execute actions in one go instead of creating multiple if and else statements.

Can somebody help I can achieve this ?

Comment: is there any reason you are passing function name instead of actual function in the map? e.g. `['action1', {functionName: f1, functionParams: ['any','any1']}]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference and call a function by passing its name as a string (without doing some `eval` black magic that I cannot in good conscience recommend). Instead, you should pass the function itself:

```ts
export function f1(param1: string, param2: string) { }

export function f2(param3: string) { }

// Change your interface to accept a function instead of a string:
interface Metadata {
    invoke: (...args: any[]) => any;
    functionParams: any[];
}

// Pass f1 or f2 (the function references) instead of 'f1' or 'f2':
const testMap: Map<string, Metadata> = new Map<string, Metadata>([
    ['action1', { invoke: f1, functionParams: ['any', 'any1'] }],
    ['action2', { invoke: f2, functionParams: ['any2'] }]
])
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAjACgA4EMBOWC2KAXIgM5Q4xgDmANItnvgEwnmU0CUiA3gLAAoRMMQQEpOABsApgDpJcamgDkACWmSFy%20owIoduAs04BuQQF9Bg0JFgJkzTIfwBmNhSrVu-ISLFgJGXlFFQB3OBxJABNtBmcXUwsrAQB6FMQAYQALLBppRABPOBAcRCooaRxgLAh8qDhEGtqMKEbkcGh4JCpyaSwoxDhgNvZPIkFyyuraxABZaSh%20rEXeQREysAA3OABraRI0WSPcalISXIKAbQBdbgBeAD5GsAKzX2EbToQABWcz56u1zelgEgjSiF%20pFIyBQg1KwGYiDQUCy%20U%20diQOGkwEq0kg0lI3B6FX6g2GylQyjhiApzGU4wE-nIiAq5FmWAwJHZGAAPKMaPR5ososssE87ogwNJQnMOXyPAK5gslosHmhLmsRJdlDUMShYjwNts9iRUPR0V1fkx-tqLrEdS99ddEOZrrRNcJbV8wHT6IaqMb9g5zR0MVaCDaHQU6c7XYJbslwQBRAAe0ggIAqDOAESRTNalzABGkfvatktf3oAd2%20VdZJZBKg3O8HtE4ikcgUSmU1Z2nliRfwJZpoRgKLiTAWlTOsQtPz%20nFbvekhyOc7A4fwhOBgiAA)